Qiskit VQC - how does VQC associate the measurement results with labels?
I'm working through the example here, and am struggling to see at what stage it is specified how the measurement results/ or expectations collected from the circuit are used to decide which label to give the data.
My gut feeling is they are using the measurement/expectation results gathered in some classical machine learning algorithm that then decides which label to attribute to the state.
But if this was the case, does this defeat the point of the quantum machine learning - If I encode my feature vectors, perform no ansatz and then do classical machine learning , this should be the same as doing classical machine learning to begin with. Is the hope that the ansatz is doing something sophisticated to make new better feature vectors out of the old ones and then return to classical machine learning?
